# How to import File in IONIC 3?

Tags: angular, file, cordova, module, ionic3

I have a strange pb with the add of file module in app.module.ts

I have already install and the plugin with this command line:

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file
npm install @ionic-native/file
```

But when I decide to make a `import { File } from '@ionic-native/file';` and add the File on `@NgModule({  providers: [File] });` I get a strange error.

You can show on this picture my error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WclQw.png)

```
SOMEONE CAN HELP ME PLEASE TO SOLVE THIS ?

import { FileOpener } from '@ionic-native/file-opener/ngx';
import { File } from '@ionic-native/file'; 
// import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
// import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { BluetoothSerial } from '@ionic-native/bluetooth-serial/ngx';
import { Toast } from '@ionic-native/toast/ngx';


@NgModule({
declarations: [
MyApp,
HomePage,
],
imports: [
 BrowserModule,
 // HttpModule,
 IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
],
bootstrap: [IonicApp],
entryComponents: [
 MyApp,
 HomePage
],
providers: [
 File,
 StatusBar,
 BluetoothSerial,
 SplashScreen,
 Printer,
 Toast,
 FileOpener,

{provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler},
]
})
```

Comment: Plesae include your code in the post please. Thank you!

Comment: import { FileOpener } from '@ionic-native/file-opener/ngx';
import { File } from '@ionic-native/file'; 

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    // HttpModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage
  ],
  providers: [
    File,
    StatusBar,
    BluetoothSerial,
    SplashScreen,
    Printer,
    Toast,
    FileOpener,
    
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler},
    
  ]
})

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to import the file in providers

Answer (score 0):

Man, do you make an instance of the file, isn't? This problem is because "this.file" is undefined therefore the function writeFile is unknown.

Comment: thanks to reply , in my construtor i have an instance of the file